# Track my girlfriend's stolen computer

Tags: chrome, facebook, skype, gmail

My girlfriend just told me that her computer was stolen, the computer was hibernated and the second the thief turn the computer on a lots a things will open automatically. I'm hoping I can get the computer location, or at least an IP address when the computer turns on

It is a Windows 7, below the services that will pop up (most promising first):

- Skype
- Chrome with at least:

  - GMail ( google hangouts runs service )
  - Facebook
  - Duolingo
  - Google Translate
  - Pandora (through Hola Unblocker extension)
- Lots of useless PDFs and Word files

Is it possible to track any (or most) of those services and get some information when the computer turns on?

PS: I'm working on the assumption that the computer have not being turn on because her skype account is offline since before the thief

<s>PS2: I'm going to try to contact someone from those companies, but I don't think they will give a damn</s>

PS2: She changed her Google and Facebook passwords for privacy concernes. Skype stuff was really helpfull, I will post their info has an answer

Answer (score 7):

Down at the bottom-right corner of the Gmail inbox is a "last account activity" line with a "details" link.  You can click on that link to get a list of IP addresses that the account has been accessed from.

Comment: Unfortunately she just changed her Google and Facebook passwords for privacy issues, the cookie will not be valid anymore

Comment: @RSFalcon7 - Maybe you can't get this information, but I'm wondering if Google/Facebook will log attempts with a recently expired password?  You're going to have to turn this information over to the police anyways...

Comment: Unfortunately brazilian police don't give a damn, they didn't even allow her to properly register the theft because they were "too busy", running an operation on the other side of the town, she had to do it online and they will only look at it during next week, when the computer will most likely be wiped already.

Comment: Google will notify you of the IP of repeated failed login attempts.  But that rather assumes the thief is a moron and doesn't wipe the machine and also that you can get someone at the ISP to be willing to hand over the physical location of a particular IP address to someone with the authority and/or ability to actually go visiting.

Answer (score 5):

If you type '/showplaces' on any Skype conversation, Skype will show you the "endpoints" used by your account.

Send this information to "Skype Police Dept" (polrequest@skype.net) and they help you out.